# Updating SQL Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

So I have a table with 6 columns, each column corresponds to a certain product type. Each column holds a number that corresponds to the number of times people have chosen that product type.

```
A | B | C | D | E | F
---------------------
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

So if the user picks type `A`, then I want to update column `A`'s number from `0` to `1`. So here's the SQL code I wrote:

```
$link = new PDO('***;dbname=***;charset=UTF-8','***','***');
$stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE table SET :column=:num");
$stmt->bindParam(':column', $column);
$stmt->bindParam(':num', $num);
$stmt->execute();
```

But it's not updating anything at all. So i'm guessing there is something wrong with the SQL code, most likely having to do with the column placeholder `:column`. Can anyone tell me the *right* SQL code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make sure, `$column` is in an accepted list of values. Next, you can't bind `:column`  you will have assign it like so:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare('UPDATE table SET ' . $column .' = :num'); 
$stmt->bindParam(':num', $num);
$stmt->execute();
```

If you were going to check for a valid `$column` I would use

`$valid_column = preg_match('/[a-z0-9_]/i, $column);`

or a sufficient replace (`preg_replace`). Though you would likely wrap it in a try/catch and set exceptions to be thrown in your PDO instance to make sure it's even legit.

Comment: To teach good practices, the injection of $column into the SQL would deserve some escaping.

Comment: I would never suggest a type of assignment or mass assignment in this fashion.  So yes, +1.  I'm bender from the future ;)

Comment: Um, no, don't escape it.  I'd do a check of 'is the string given **exactly** one in this set'.  Anything else raises the possibility of problems.  Your given check won't restrict the column selected to the 'proper' list, and is only valid for the english/latin alphabet; if you check some of the other questions on this site, you'll see database table/columns with names with non-latin characters.  It also won't allow 'escaped' names (which may have been reserved words, not usually valid column names).