# SQL Fetching single scalar using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

This question is more on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424009/updating-sql-column). So I want to retrieve the number in a certain column. So let's say the table looks like this:

```
A | B | C | D | E | F
---------------------
0 | 50| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

Let's say the user enters in `B`, I want to go fetch the current number in the table, which is `50`. This is my SQL code:

```
$link = new PDO('**;dbname=**;charset=UTF-8','**','**');
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT MAX(:type) as max FROM table");
$stmt->bindParam(':type', $type);
$stmt->execute();
$used = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$used = $used["max"];
```

But this is just returning `B` rather than the number. How do I change my code to get the number? Thanks

Comment: this does not look like a table. which is column and which is row?

Comment: @codingbiz the `A B C...` are the column names, there is only one row. That row contains the number for each type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(:type) as max FROM table
```

Assuming `:type` gets set to "B", this will be executed as:

```
SELECT MAX("B") as max FROM table
```

The MAX of something with just one value will be that one value, i.e.:

```
SELECT "B" as max FROM table
```

Most likely you want to select the MAX from that column, not the string:

```
SELECT MAX(B) as max FROM table
```

Which you can do like this:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT MAX($type) as max FROM table");
```

Obviously, this is vulnerable to SQL injection if `$type` comes from a user, but if you're getting a table name from a user, then you're doing something wrong anyway.

It's also possible that your table would make more sense like this:

```
type | value
------------
A    | 0
B    | 50
C    | 0
```

And then you could get it with:

```
SELECT MAX(value) FROM tableName WHERE type = :type
```