# escaping column name with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have a function that's like

```
function getInfoById($id, $info) {

}
```

the idea is to have a query be `"SELECT $info FROM table WHERE id = $id"`

This doesn't work with PDO because you can't escape column names. I also don't really want to use `"SELECT *"` because doesn't that return a bigger result set and use more memory?

Comment: it should work fine... try `id = '$id'"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping column names in PDO statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542627/escaping-column-names-in-pdo-statements)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, PDO does not have a builtin function for delimiting identifiers like table names and column names.  The `PDO::quote()` function is only for string literals and date literals.

For what it's worth, when I worked on Zend Framework, I implemented a `quoteIdentifier()` function.

You're right that `SELECT *` fetches all columns, likely using more memory and spoiling the benefit of covering indexes.

My recommendation is to create an **allowlist** column names.  That is, make sure $info actually names a column of `table`.  Then you don't need to worry about the column name not existing, or containing a strange character, or anything.  You get to control the set of columns that are legitimate to put in the query.

You should also delimit the column name anyway.  Delimited identifiers are necessary if the column name contains punctuation, whitespace, international characters, or matches an SQL reserved word.  See [Do different databases use different name quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214309/do-different-databases-use-different-name-quote/214344#214344)

```
function getInfoById($id, $info) {
    // you can make this a literal list, or query it from DESC or INFORMATION_SCHEMA
    $cols = array('col1', 'col2', 'col3');

    if (array_search($info, $cols) === false) {
      return false;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT `$info` FROM table WHERE id = :id";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    if ($stmt === false) {
      return false;
    }
    . . .
}
```

I show more examples of allowlisting in my presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies) or my book [SQL Antipatterns, Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Comment: I agree, whitelisting is the way to go.

Comment: `in_array` with `true` for strict comparison

Answer (score 6):

I would just filter it out with some regex. Keep it simple.

Also, you should bind `$id` and have it be `:id`

```
$info = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_]+/', '', $info);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT $info FROM table WHERE id = :id'); 
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Well it's better than interpolating any arbitrary $info, but it's an incomplete solution.  For example, if my column name is `order` (an SQL reserved word), the query breaks.

Comment: @BillKarwin bill, I agree, though I was just making a point.  Like you said above, whitelisting is the way to go, it's how I prefer to handle these things myself.  I said the same thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424009/updating-sql-column/13424037#13424037  Just went through your Injection slideshow, good stuff.

Comment: Well, add quotes around it SELECT "$info" FROM...  That should also allow query to be used as column

Answer (score -1):

What about using quote and substr.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE `' . substr($db->quote($field), 1, -1) . '` = :id';
```

This will remove the quotes surrounding the escaped field.

Comment: Dangerous! If `$field` contains a Backtick, this fails horribly and allows SQL-Injections.