# compose mysql query in python

Tags: python, mysql

I want to fetch all rows from MySQL table with

```
query = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE last_name=%s"
cursor.execute(query, ("employees","Smith"))
```

but I'm getting 
`You have an error in your SQL syntax`. When I try

```
query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE last_name=%s"
cursor.execute(query, ("Smith",))
```

all is fine.
Documentation says
`cursor.execute(operation, params=None, multi=False)
The parameters found in the tuple or dictionary params are bound to the variables in the operation.`[link on docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

Comment: You can't use a table name as parameter.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I think I will follow another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13448443/1403984 about whitelisting

Comment: Glenfant's answer is correct and safe assuming the column name isn't untrusted input.

Answer (score 1):

The first will generate an SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 'employees' WHERE last_name='smith'
```

The parameters are SQL quoted.

If you really need to have a table name as param, you must proceed in 2 steps:

```
table_name = 'employees'
query_tpl = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE last_name=%s"
query = query_tpl.format(table_name)
cursor.execute(query, ("Smith",))
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to add the **quote** symbol. So the query will be like

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE last_name='Smith'
```

Change both your query to

```
query = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE last_name='%s'"
query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE last_name='%s'"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use a parameter for the table name in the execute call. 
But you can use Python string interpolation for that:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE last_name=%s" %("employees","Smith")
cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: Params are not quoted. You should care of security.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use a table name as a parameter. you are generating invalid sql with your code that is putting quotes around each string. the table name cannot have quotes around it.

sql you are generating

```
select * from 'employees' where last_name = 'Smith'
```

What sql you want

```
select * from employees where last_name = 'Smith'
```

you would have to format the string first like the example below.

```
query = "SELECT * from {} wherre last_name ='{}'"
cursor.execute(query.format("employees","Smith"))
```

using code like this does open up the possibility of SQL injection. so please bear that in mind.

Comment: Bad idea. You don't quote params and may open your app to SQL injections.

Comment: totally agree and should not do this, hence why i said opens up the possibility of sql injection.

Answer (score -1):

```
query="SELECT * FROM %s WHERE name=%s",(employees,smith)
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Try this one. Hopefully it works for you.